# Solving for A when $f(x) = A\sin x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let A be a positive constant. If the graph of the function $f(x) = A\sin x$ intersects the graph of its derivative perpendicularly, then what does A equal?

(This problem was provided by a professor -- it's not homework.) I understand that $A\sin x$ intersects $A\cos x$, but I don't know how they intersect perpendicularly, as their graphs are not linear (so the angle $\neq 90$ at the point of intersection). And there is no constant $A$ (at least that I know of) that can linearize trigonometric functions. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

He is asking for the values of $A$ for which the two curves $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ have perpendicular tangent lines at the points where they intersect.

Let me know if you want some help solving the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the tangents of two perpendicular lines are -1 when you multiply them: a slope of 1/2 is perpendicular to -2, and when you multiply them you get 1.

You know the derivative of $A\sin x$ is $A \cos x$. So where does $(A \cos x)(A\sin x) = 1$?

$A^2 \sin x \cos x = 1$

$A^2 \cos x = \frac{1}{\sin x} $

$A^2 = \frac{1}{ \sin x \cos x }$

Note that $2 \sin x \cos x = \sin 2x$ so the last expression could be

$A^2 = \frac{1}{ \sin 2x / 2 } = \frac{2}{ \sin 2x}$

and you can get what A would be at that point.

Answer (score 0):

A = sqrt(2) because the points at which they meet are x = pi*n - 3/4*pi for n equals all integer values. Since the slopes are the same or completely opposite at all of these values you can just look at x=pi/4 then just take the derivative of each of these functions at x=pi/4 and you have yourself the good ole rise over run which you can put in the form of a vector in our case <1, A(1/sqrt(2))> and <1, -A(1/sqrt(2))> so you just take the dot product of these two vectors and set it equal to 0, proof of being perpendicular, and since you only have positive solutions you're left with sqrt(2)

Comment: Please consider editing your answer for readability. Use MathJax/LaTeX markup, and break it into paragraphs, etc. It will be more likely to be seen and receive upvotes this way.